# Most palindromic prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-complexity, palindrome

> A prime number is the most palindromic prime if it has more nontrivial
> palindromic representations across number bases than all primes
> below it.
>
> Nontrivial representation means we are not counting one digit
> representations as palindromes (since number $p$ is
> one-digit-palindromic in all number bases $b\gt p$), and we are also
> not counting the "$11$" representation since every $p$ can be written
> like that in the base $b=p-1$. 
>  In other words, we are
> considering the number bases $b\le p-2$ only.

I've found that it is sufficient to check number bases $b\le \lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+1$ 
(This excludes $2$ digit representations as they are composite and divisible by $a$ for digits $a\ge2$)

I've computed the first $21$ terms so far, below:

*(checked / iterated over the first $10^6$ prime numbers so far)*

*Read Columns*: $1 -$ the prime number, $2 -$number of palindromic representations (number bases), $3 -$ index of the prime number, $4 -$ number bases in which the prime number is palindromic

```
2 0 1. []
5 1 3. [2]
17 2 7. [2, 4]
191 3 43. [6, 9, 10]
257 4 55. [2, 4, 7, 16]
1009 5 169. [11, 15, 19, 24, 28]
4561 6 618. [4, 31, 47, 48, 57, 60]
4591 7 621. [19, 20, 24, 33, 37, 51, 54]
21601 8 2426. [12, 29, 33, 69, 108, 120, 135, 144]
54121 10 5510. [46, 47, 50, 61, 70, 76, 87, 165, 205, 220]
86677 11 8424. [2, 48, 58, 64, 66, 70, 94, 107, 113, 151, 233]
176401 12 16031. [59, 69, 73, 136, 300, 315, 336, 350, 360, 392, 400, 420]
291721 14 25365. [122, 146, 148, 172, 205, 233, 311, 390, 408, 429, 440, 442, 510, 520]
950041 15 74912. [138, 152, 192, 219, 239, 696, 728, 754, 780, 812, 819, 840, 870, 910, 936]
1259701 16 97165. [126, 147, 184, 185, 199, 279, 299, 423, 850, 884, 950, 969, 975, 988, 1020, 1105]
1670761 18 126103. [10, 121, 161, 348, 591, 918, 936, 945, 952, 1020, 1071, 1080, 1092, 1105, 1170, 1190, 1224, 1260]
3880801 20 275324. [40, 369, 388, 472, 1400, 1440, 1470, 1540, 1568, 1575, 1584, 1617, 1650, 1680, 1760, 1764, 1800, 1848, 1925, 1960]
5654881 21 390695. [249, 387, 977, 1683, 1760, 1785, 1836, 1848, 1870, 1890, 1904, 1980, 2016, 2040, 2079, 2142, 2160, 2244, 2295, 2310, 2376]
13759201 22 895446. [292, 528, 1253, 2646, 2700, 2730, 2800, 2808, 2912, 2925, 2940, 3024, 3120, 3150, 3185, 3276, 3360, 3510, 3528, 3600, 3640, 3675]
14414401 24 935289. [262, 2730, 2772, 2800, 2860, 2880, 2912, 2925, 3003, 3080, 3120, 3150, 3168, 3276, 3300, 3360, 3432, 3465, 3520, 3575, 3600, 3640, 3696, 3744]
15135121 26 978870. [292, 473, 533, 611, 1565, 2772, 2808, 2860, 2940, 2970, 3003, 3024, 3080, 3120, 3185, 3234, 3276, 3432, 3465, 3510, 3528, 3640, 3696, 3780, 3822, 3861]
```

This sequence is not in the OEIS.

I've noticed that all terms so far except the $4$-th $(191)$ and $8$-th one $(4591)$, are a hypotenuse of a primitive pythagorean triple and can be written as a sum of two squares ($p=4k+1$). 
These two 'rouge' terms cannot be written as a sum of three squares ($p=8k+7$).

You can also notice that some primes on the list are better than previous by two bases, rather than by just one more as most so far.

> Have primes generated by this property been observed before? Are there any other properties they might share?
>
> How can they be generated/computed faster than checking every prime for being palindromic in every number base up to $\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+1$, and adding it to the list if it beats the current record?

To speed up the search; Perhaps a lower bound on gaps between two consecutive terms can be found or properties that exclude some sets of number bases can be stated?

Comment: Most of the research on palindromic numbers has focused on base 10 palindromes, and a decent amount on binary palindromes. Other bases have for the most part been ignored.

Comment: Suppose $b$ is a two-digit palindrome in some base $b$, then $p=ab+a=a(b+1)$ for some $a$. Since $p$ is prime, this gives $a=1$, so $p=11_b$, but that's forbidden. So $p$ is at least a three-digit palindrome, giving $101_b=b^2+1\ge p$, so that's why you found $b\le\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor+1$.

Comment: @Mastrem That's what I meant to say when I wrote that we are excluding $2$ digit examples.